# Learning Python the hard way printing output in sublime text vs cmd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

Doing Exercises from http://learnpythonthehardway.org

My System Info --- Python2.7.6 // Windows 8 // Sublime Text 2 Default Python build system

Executing the following code from exercise 10:

`for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
    print "%s\r" %i,`

### I understand what's going on.

Now, when I remove the `,` after `%i` in print command (line2). I get the following output in sublime text.

```
/

-
|
\
|
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Where does the "empty string" and CR in line 2 of output come from ? It's not there in the list.

I Run the same code in cmd I get this output

```
D:\learn python the hard way>python ex10.py
/
-
|
\
|

D:\learn python the hard way>
```

The "empty string" and CR comes at the last line now.

**What's going on ?**

Comment: There's a `while True:` line above those two in the example code, have you tried that? Add in the `while` line and try in the command prompt and you'll see what the code was supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: @Marius I know that it shows a "cmd processing..." symbol in CMD. But where does the CR come in the last line from ? It's not in the array given in the for loop right ?

Comment: In python 2, if you put a comma after a print statement, it doesn't automatically add a newline character. Without a comma, whenever you print it will add a newline. How exactly that's interacting with the `\r` characters in the code, I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @Marius Fair answer. But you know, the strange thing is that, in the infinite loop without the comma, the "empty string" does not come. But it only comes up does when there is no infinite loop.